# PHP curl POST headers returns null on Laravel middleware with HTTPS

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php-curl, laravel-middleware

with http domain, it works, returning the expected output but with https, headers are null. Below is my attempt.

**POST CURL**

```
$fields = [];
$headers = ['_token: 58SkLjsNMk0', 'Authorization: 6059DLaf39d4141' ];

$cURLConnection = curl_init('<https domain>/api/auth/check');
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$res = curl_exec($cURLConnection);
curl_close($cURLConnection);

dd($res);
```

**Middleware**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Api
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next){
        return response()->json($request->header('Authorization'));
    }
}
```

Any help, suggestions is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: does the same request work in e.g. postman?

Comment: @apokryfos tried with postman, same result

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the HTTPS version has some 30x redirect in it?
Try adding `curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` to make cURL follow the redirection.

Also, just for debugging purposes(!), please try to add -

```
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

These well disable the verification of the certificate's name against host / the peer's SSL certificate.
(Add them all before `curl_exec()`)

Comment: no luck. still returning null